# Typeorm query array type in postgres

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

```
const query = userConnection.getRepository(User).createQueryBuilder('user');

const result = await query.where("user.role @> ARRAY[:role]", { role: 'Super-Admin' })
               .getMany();

return result;
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity()
export class User extends BaseEntity{
    @Column({type: 'text', array: true})
    role: UserRole[];
}
```

I am getting error 'operator does not exist: text @> text[]'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: As the erorr expressed, you are using text to compare with array which postgresql not supported.Do you want to find the user who has multiple roles except admin?

Comment: I want to find all users who have role Admin. An user might have multiple role eg {'Admin', 'Agency', 'Student'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it

```
query.andWhere(":role = ANY ( string_to_array(user.role, ','))", { role });
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-comparisons.html

```
expression operator ANY (array expression)
```

> The right-hand side is a parenthesized expression, which must yield an
> array value. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to
> each element of the array using the given operator, which must yield a
> Boolean result. The result of ANY is "true" if any true result is
> obtained. The result is "false" if no true result is found (including
> the case where the array has zero elements).

So you can use `ANY` function  to find the user has multiple roles containing admin

```
const result = await query.where(':role = ANY (user.role)', { role: 'Super-Admin' });
```

Comment: this is how I solved it

query.andWhere(":role = ANY ( string_to_array(user.role, ','))", { role });